# Problems with extracting information from a `.zip` file

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm having problems with extracting information from a `.zip` file. I'm doing it as follows:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   zipObj.extractall()
```

But it gives the following error:

```
----------------------------------------------------
OSError            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [58], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from zipfile import ZipFile
----> 3 with ZipFile('https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
      4    zipObj.extractall()

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py:1248, in ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1246 while True:
   1247     try:
-> 1248         self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
   1249     except OSError:
   1250         if filemode in modeDict:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip'
```

Comment: URLs are not files.  You cannot use `ZipFIle(url, 'r')` to decompress a URL.  You need to copy the URL to a temporary local file and unzip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruh, just use `geopandas.read_file()` it's smart. [Documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file) [For Zips](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html#:%7E:text=If%20there%20are%20multiple%20datasets%20in%20a%20folder%20in%20the%20ZIP%20file%2C%20you%20also%20have%20to%20specify%20the%20filename)

```
import geopandas

url = "https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip"

df = geopandas.read_file(url)
print(df)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A question, now with the file extracted, how can I create a variable and select only this file  `41MUE250GC_SIR.shp`

Comment: What do you mean by select? Save it? Analyze it?

Comment: I would like to create a variable, where it specifically receives the `41MUE250GC_SIR.shp` file that is inside that `.zip` file. For example, if the file was on my computer, I could do it like this: `PR = gpd.read_file('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/Maps/PR/41MUE250GC_SIR.shp')`. In the case here I used the `geopandas` package which reads the `.shp` file. So how could I do something similar to this, i.e. create a variable named `PR`, for example, that specifically receives the file `41MUE250GC_SIR.shp` ?

Comment: lol, just let `geopandas` do the work then, see my edit.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I ended up making the question more difficult than it really is. Thank you for your help, but, how do I read only `41MUE250GC_SIR.shp` file from the url?

Comment: Check out the documentation. The For Zips link has instructions on how to select a particular document in a zip.

Answer (score 1):

Zipfile cannot extract files directly from the internet, you have to download them first. You could do it within the same script using the `requests` package:

```py
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

req = requests.get("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip", allow_redirects=True)

with open("pr_municipios.zip", "wb") as file:
    file.write(req.content)


with ZipFile('pr_municipios.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   zipObj.extractall()
```